# Inverse function in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

How do I find the inverse function of $f: X\to Y$ where $X,Y$ both are subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ and $f$ is defined as $f(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$.

Comment: Have you studied linear algebra? You learn about inverses of matrices there. If not, do what you learned for single-variable functions. Set $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$, and solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Yess, got it... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}}_f\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}1 &1 \\1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}$$ find inverse of matrix  to find $f^{-1}$

Answer (score 3):

So this is a system of linear equations, so the core thing is to solve the system. For larger degree inputs and outputs, matrix inversion is the way to go, but for this case, solving the equations without them isn't too horrible:

$f(x, y) = (u, v)$ -> $f^{-1} (u, v) = (x, y)$

$x + y = u$

$x - y = v$

$u + v = 2x + 0 = 2x$

$x = \frac{u + v}{2}$

$y = u - x = u - \frac{u + v}{2} = \frac{u - v}{2}$

$f^{-1} (u, v) = (\frac{u + v}{2}, \frac{u - v}{2})$

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $(x,y)=g(u,v)$ the following system

$$\begin{align}
u=&x+y\\
v=&x-y
\end{align}$$

You find that

$$\begin{align}
x={u+v\over 2}\\
y={u-v\over 2}
\end{align}$$

Therefore

$$g(u,v)=f^{-1}(u,v)=\left({u+v\over 2},{u-v\over 2}\right)$$